# how to control the Json output of a Java class

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I have a REST API response object class which contains various members and their getters and setters.
one of the members is

```
private String name;
```

and it is JSON'ized fine to something like

```
"name": "John",
```

However, for some reason I want to change this member to be

```
private Name name;
```

where Name is

```
public class Name implements Something {
    private String str;

    public Name(String name) {
        this.str = name;
    }       
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return str;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return str;
    }
    //... other methods
}

But now it is JSON'ized to something like
"name": {
    "value": "John"
},
```

is there anyway i can annotate the name field so to use the toString() so its JSON representation still looks like below?

```
"name": "<name.toString()>"
```

Comment: I just assumed you're using Jackson. If you're not, let me know and I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna change the toString() result, just rewrite toString().
If you are using Json tools, for example fastjson, use  @JsonProperty("")